# Excluding location path from file paths

Tags: nginx, config, httpserver

In config file,

```
location /i/ {
    root /data/w3;
}
```

The `/data/w3/i/top.gif` file will be sent in response to the `/i/top.gif` request. How can I set it to ignore `i` in file paths? Indeed I need `/i/top.gif` to be mapped to `/data/w3/top.gif`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
location /i/ {
    alias /data/w3/;
}
```